# Total derivative of function with not continuous derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I was wondering if the following function is totally differentiable in $(0, 0)$:
$$f(x, y) = \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$$ and $f(0,0) = 0$. I know that the partial derivatives are
$$f_x(x, y)= \frac{2xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)y^2}, \quad f_y(x, y) = \frac{x^4-x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$
Is it correct that both of these partial derivatives are not continuous in $(0,0)$? For $f_x(x,y)$, one can consider the limits $\lim_{h\to 0}f_x(h, h)=1/2$ and $\lim_{h\to 0}f_x(h, 0) = 0$, so this derivative can't be continuous, similarly for $f_y(x,y)$, which also can't be continuous, and in summary, $f$ can't be totally differentiable in $(0,0)$.

All I'm wondering is if my thoughts are correct here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should find the value of partial derivatives at the point by the definition (via limits).

We have $f(x,0) = 0$ and $f(0,0) = 0$. Then,
$$f'_x(0,0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x,0) - f(0,0)}{x-0} = 0$$
Similarly, we get
$$f'_y(0,0) = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(0,y) - f(0,0)}{y-0} = 0$$
Hence we need to check if the following equality is true:
$$\lim_{x\to0 \\ y\to0} \frac{f(x,y) - f(0,0) - 0 - 0}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \overset ? = 0$$
which is equivalent to
$$\lim_{x\to0 \\ y\to0} \frac{\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}= \lim_{x\to0 \\ y\to0} \frac{x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \overset ?= 0$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! I understand the idea, but why do we need to take $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in the third step? Everything else is clear

Comment: @Gecko1111 The definition of differentiability says: $$\Delta f (\textbf{x}) - \nabla f (\textbf{x})\Delta \textbf x = o(\rho (\textbf{x} + \Delta\textbf{x}, \textbf x))$$ where $\textbf{x}  = (x,y)$ and $\rho(\textbf{x} + \Delta\textbf{x}, \textbf x) = \sqrt{\Delta x^2+ \Delta y^2}$.

Comment: Oh right, I did not see that the root is the norm of $(\Delta x ,\Delta y)$. I calculated the limit using $y =ax, a \in \mathbb{R}$, then the limit becomes $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a}{(1+a^2)^{3/2}}$. So that $f$ is not totally differentiable.